# How to use isFocused method to change state

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` in my react-native app. Since the component does not provide an `onPress` method which would normally detect a touch gesture, I would like to use the `isFocused` method which according to documentation, "*returns true if the TextInput is currently focused*; false otherwise". My question is what is the convention for watching the return value of a method in react-native? I would like to be able to alter my UI in case the method evaluates to either true/false.

I've provided my setup below. As you can see, as an example, I would like my view to show "Hello" if `isFocused` evaluates to true and "Hi" if false however this implementation does not obviously won't work for what I'm trying to do.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Animated, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, Touchable, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete'
import { GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY } from '@env'

export default function SearchComponent({ expanded = false, setExpanded }) {

    const ref = useRef();
    const [top] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))

    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.timing(top, {
            toValue: !expanded ? 70 : 80,
            duration: 150,
            useNativeDriver: false
        }).start();
    }, [expanded, top]);

    return (
        < Animated.View style={{ top }
        } >
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                ref={ref}
                placeholder='Search'
                onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                    console.log(data, details);
                }}
                query={{
                    key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
                    language: 'en',
                    components: 'country:ca'
                }}
            />
            {ref.current?.isFocused() ? (
                <Text>Hello</Text>
            ) : (<Text>Hi</Text>)
            }
        </Animated.View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [use-is-focused hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/)

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function SearchComponent({ expanded = false, setExpanded }) {
     const isFocused = useIsFocused();
     ....
     // based on that value, you render something different
}
```